# SQL FROM_UNIXTIME Not Correct

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have the following SQL:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(1392354000)
```

When I insert that into the database in my insert statement, the value that gets saved is:

```
2014-02-13 19:00:00
```

However, this is not correct, because it should be like this:

```
2014-02-14 00:00:00
```

If you copy and paste the timestamp at http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php it will show the 14th of Feb.

What can I do to make my timestamp be the 14th of Feb (not the 13th)?  Preferably, it would be as shown above (`2014-02-14 00:00:00`).

Comment: Looks like the URL you posted is having a different timezone set than that in your mysql default-time-zone in my.cnf which is why you get different dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the timezone of your mysql is not same as the URL you are testing with.

In the URL the timezone is UTC.

So to test this you can try this

First check the timezone set for your mysql server with the following command

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

This will show you the timezone result, and if its set to UTC you will get something as

```
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| +00:00             |
+--------------------+
```

else you will get some other result.

Now if its something else which is more likely as you mentioned

Try this

```
SET @@global.time_zone='+00:00';
```

Now your mysql server is having UTC timezone and then run the command

```
mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME(1392354000) ;
+---------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1392354000) |
+---------------------------+
| 2014-02-14 10:30:00       |
+---------------------------+
```

Here are few ways to change the timezone of your mysql server

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/how-to-change-mysql-server-time-zone

Comment: Thank you.  To solve this, I added `date.timezone="UTC"` to my php.ini.